# E[X| X>Y] for independent X, Y ~ N(0,1)

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am looking for conditional expectation $E[X| X>Y]$ for independent $X, Y \sim N(0,1).$ I just showed that $P(X\leq a | X>Y) = \Phi(a)^2$, where $\Phi(a)$ is CDF for Normal$(0,1)$, but I don't know how to compute integral in order to obtain expected value.

Comment: This is simply $E(\max(X,Y))$ which is easy to find as the distribution of $\max(X,Y)$ is easy to find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewriting and using linearity of expectation,

$$
E[X | X > Y] = E[X | X - Y > 0] = E[X - Y | X - Y > 0] + E[Y | X - Y > 0].
$$

Define now $X' = -X, Y' = -Y$. Then

$$
E[Y | X - Y > 0] = E[-Y' | Y' - X' > 0] = -E[Y' | Y' - X' > 0].
$$

However, note that $Y', X' \sim X, Y$, so we have $E[Y' | Y' - X' > 0] = E[X | X - Y > 0]$. Inserting back, then,

$$
E[X | X > Y] = E[X - Y | X - Y > 0] - E[X | X > Y],
$$

implying that

$$
E[X | X > Y] = \frac{E[X - Y | X - Y > 0]}{2}.
$$

Finally, note that $X - Y$ is a a normal R.V. with mean 0 and variance 2, so $E[ X - Y | X - Y > 0]$ is [easy to find](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88114/expected-value-of-normal-distribution-given-that-distribution-is-positive).